# Please help me finding my voice type

Tags: voice

I understand you're probably bored with questions like this, but it's really important for me and I can't get a definite answer for years now.

I'm 26 years old. 
The lowest note I can sing is E2, the highest I can hit (not sing, it's very thin) without the falsetto is C5-C#5. The falsetto ends at G5-A5
My voice gets strained (but doesn't slide into falsetto) around E4-F4.

My previous vocal teacher (whom I don't trust) defined me as a lyrical baritone.

My current vocal teacher says I'm a dramatic tenor and she thinks my (working) range is about 2 octaves, up to G#4, though recently during the warm-up we got to A#4.

What I just recorded to show you [the range](https://soundcloud.com/sleep-project/range/s-5QNax)

Some [additional songs](https://soundcloud.com/sleep-project/sets/high-to-low) to show you my timbre.

Thank you!

Comment: This may sound strange, but why is it so important? It sounds like it's early days yet, so things will change anyway, and even if there was an exact label, what difference would it make? I'm curious, as when I sing with others, if I can't reach one harmony, I'll find another. Alone, I'll find a key that fits.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I didn't include that information because I didn't want to include too many details. It is important for me because I always tend to sing higher stuff, I find that those high notes (not extremely high, but up to around A4) express my feelings in the best way possible. It's harder for me to feel that I'm singing or performing when I do it in the lower register. But I don't want to waste my time at trying if that's not possible. I also don't want to harm my voice because I don't really imagine my life without singing.

Answer (score 3):

There would be no way to answer this here.  For one thing, the two fachs are very similar.  My first thought is almost that the answer doesn't matter that much when you are in your early studies.  As you gain command of your voice, improve your vocal technique, and work with various repertoire, you will find that certain spots speak better, come out easier, etc.  There will come a time when your natural vocal strengths will be much more obvious, and you will know if you need to switch.

Also, the fachs are discreet in ways that real voices are not.  You could be naturally between the two, and may find that you develop into one role or the other through your training.

A word of warning: I am not, myself, a deep expert on the voice.  I work with vocalists professionally, however, and this answer reflects my experiences.  If an experienced operatic vocal teacher chimes in with different information, I would defer to their experience.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your thoughts. Didn't know it's possible to develop in one way or another, that one can do that with training. Many sources state that you only have what you were born with. If I only knew that I can become a low tenor in 5 years of hard training I would go for it.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that you can necessarily go in whatever direction you choose -- your voice should have some natural tendencies -- but there is a simple truth: there is an infinite continuum of the male voice, but only 19 male fachs.  This means that for most males, there must be at least *some* range of choice available.  Only time, effort, and learning will tell you whether what you're doing is really within that range.  But if, say, several years into your studies, you are still straining at the top, that's a big clue about whether you are headed in a reasonable direction.

Comment: One more thought to add: the stakes aren't as high as you might fear. If it turns out you are training in a slightly wrong fach, it's not as if the vocal instruction you got until that point is totally useless. Good breath support is good breath support, good posture is good posture, etc.  There may be a few habits to re-learn, but that time, effort and learning won't be lost just because everything isn't perfect at the very beginning of your studies.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your words of inspiration/

I don't even think that having a great range is very important or that having high notes is that important. It's just that if I sing in baritone range it's most of the not so convincing, perhaps because I don't have exactly right timbre for singing in baritone range. But when I try singing in more tenor range I face "range" problems. So you can see it's not your average insecure Joe. I just really want to find my way (no Frank Sinatra pun intended!)

Comment: Seems like with your help I'm finally becoming calm about this whole thing. I can't stop singing anyway.